# JS semicolon removes 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error why?

Tags: javascript

My code is this:

```
message.labels.forEach(/…/) container.data.push(message);
```

It throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
When I add a semicolon after the `forEach` function it doesn't throw it anymore. I only change the semicolon there, I checked it with my git.

Why does it do it? Feels like I'm missing some JS fundamentals here.

Comment: What do you think the code does? Looks like a lack of understanding loops.

Comment: Use linting tool like JsLint, JsHint, JSCS, EsLint. That will prevent strange bugs like your one: putting two comments on one line.

Comment: @Bergi The loop you're seeing does nothing. the `/.../` part is there to show, there is some content.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek yeah, thanks for hint. New-line also removes the error.

Comment: @MihkelL.: OK, well, it might have been possible that you'd have expected the `container.data.push(message);` to be the loop body. You really should place statements on separate lines - and even then use semicolons although ASI would do it.

Comment: I used ctrl+x and it cut the statement to same line, and then error came that I didn't expect. usually those things are of course on different lines. Probably that's why I didn't know it before. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[The semi-colon ends a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Basics).

If you leave it out, then your two statements are treated as a single one, it doesn't make any sense and the compiler throw  an error.

Comment: Yeah, but usually browser can handle it.
Line change also removes the bug. Guess browser need it then. :)

Comment: @MihkelL.: [ASI only works on linebreaks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572)

Comment: @MihkelL.  - JavaScript has well-defined rules about what to do with lines that don't end in a semicolon. A line-break doesn't necessarily end a statement, though often it does.